# Storyboard in DataTemplate doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, storyboard, datatemplate

I need to have a storyboard which could change a foreground in my TextBox. The problem is that this TextBox has to be in DataTemplate.

How can I change my xaml to have this working ?

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="contentTexBox">
            <Grid>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Pink" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="tbContent"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <TextBox Text="Test text" Width="200" Height="35" Foreground="Blue" x:Name="tbContent" BorderBrush="Purple">                   

                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand the question, because your sample works. What is the problem?

Comment: Is it changes its foreground from Pink to Blue on mouseover ?

Answer (score -1):

I did it another way but this method does not explicitly refer to the text box, so I suppose it should work in your case. The main changes are that the call to the styled `TextBox` is now implicit (because states are declared under this control) and `Background` property is changed instead of `Foreground`.

After adapting the test code I've wrote to your case, I suppose it can look more or less like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="contentCheckBox">
<Grid>
<TextBox Text="Test text" Width="200" Height="35" Foreground="Blue" BorderBrush="Purple">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            <TextBox Width="190">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Pink" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </TextBox>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
    </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas for your help. I have to set here a Target/TargetName, but I don' know how. Could you edit your answer?

Comment: and also TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" should be  TargetType="TextBox" . x:Type is in wpf

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've tested this with `x:Type` in WPF. When talking about the `TargetName`, have you tried not to set it (as written in the snippet)? `Storyboard` is defined as child element of the `TextBox`, so I suppose that you don't have to specify it explicitly.